# Drawing angled rectangles in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, tracking

I am using OpenCV and python to work on a project that involves body tracking, and I am using HSV values to find a skin tone then draw a box around it.

However although I can find the tracked object and draw a box around it the rectangles are always vertical, and I would like to know if there is anyway angle the rectangles so they better show the detected object, somewhat like the minEnclosingCircle function, but using a rectangle

The images probably explain what I am looking for better. The boxes that I am getting are green, and what I'm looking for I have drawn on in yellow. As you can see the mask shows and angled rectangle would also better encompass the selected area. I have also included the original image.

My code is:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Input image
image = cv2.imread('TestIn.png')

# Converts to grey for better reulsts
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Converts to HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# HSV values
lower_skin = np.array([5,36,53])
upper_skin = np.array([19,120,125])

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_skin, upper_skin)

mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=2)
mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=2)

# Finds contours
im2, cnts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Draws contours
for c in cnts:
    if cv2.contourArea(c) < 3000:
        continue

    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Input image:

[image: Input Image]

Output image (output boxes in green, desired boxes in yellow):

[image: output image. output boxes in green, desired boxes in yellow]

Comment: minAreaRect function computes what you want. but you have to draw the lines manually, there is no drawing function for RotatedRect objects

Comment: See section 7 in this [official OpenCV tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html#gsc.tab=0) from the documentation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to use [`cv2.minAreaRect(...)`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga3d476a3417130ae5154aea421ca7ead9&gsc.tab=0) and then [`cv2.boxPoints(...)`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaf78d467e024b4d7936cf9397185d2f5c&gsc.tab=0) to obtain a sequence of points representing the polygon in a format that can be used by other OpenCV drawing functions, such as [`cv2.drawContours(...)`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga746c0625f1781f1ffc9056259103edbc) or [`cv2.polylines(...)`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#gaa3c25f9fb764b6bef791bf034f6e26f5).

---

Based on the [example](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html#gsc.tab=0) in OpenCV documentation I added few statements to your code to achieve the desired result:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Input image
image = cv2.imread('oaHUs.jpg')

# Converts to grey for better reulsts
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Converts to HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# HSV values
lower_skin = np.array([5,36,53])
upper_skin = np.array([19,120,125])

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_skin, upper_skin)

mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=2)
mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=2)

# Finds contours
im2, cnts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Draws contours
for c in cnts:
    if cv2.contourArea(c) < 3000:
        continue

    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    ## BEGIN - draw rotated rectangle
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
    box = np.int0(box)
    cv2.drawContours(image,[box],0,(0,191,255),2)
    ## END - draw rotated rectangle

cv2.imwrite('out.png', image)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: No problem. Feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks :)