# How to draw rotated rectangle with Python

Tags: python, opencv, rotation, computer-vision, drawrectangle

I have the center coordinate, rotation angle, width and height. With this I want to draw a rotated box on the original image using the rotation angle. Is there any method in Python2.7 to achieve my requirement?

It should looks like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjnNy.jpg) as red box. I don't want to extract contour because I already have any co-ordinate you want.

I add my code here to finish this question. I use rotation matrix to find four corner points then draw lines.

```
def draw_rectangle(image, centre, theta, width, height):
theta = np.radians(theta)
c, s = np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta)
R = np.matrix('{} {}; {} {}'.format(c, -s, s, c))
# print(R)
print centre[0]
p1 = [ + width / 2,  + height / 2]
p2 = [- width / 2,  + height / 2]
p3 = [ - width / 2, - height / 2]
p4 = [ + width / 2,  - height / 2]
p1_new = np.dot(p1, R)+ centre
p2_new = np.dot(p2, R)+ centre
p3_new = np.dot(p3, R)+ centre
p4_new = np.dot(p4, R)+ centre
print p1_new
img = cv2.line(image, (int(p1_new[0, 0]), int(p1_new[0, 1])), (int(p2_new[0, 0]), int(p2_new[0, 1])), (255, 0, 0), 1)
img = cv2.line(img, (int(p2_new[0, 0]), int(p2_new[0, 1])), (int(p3_new[0, 0]), int(p3_new[0, 1])), (255, 0, 0), 1)
img = cv2.line(img, (int(p3_new[0, 0]), int(p3_new[0, 1])), (int(p4_new[0, 0]), int(p4_new[0, 1])), (255, 0, 0), 1)
img = cv2.line(img, (int(p4_new[0, 0]), int(p4_new[0, 1])), (int(p1_new[0, 0]), int(p1_new[0, 1])), (255, 0, 0), 1)
img = cv2.line(img, (int(p2_new[0, 0]), int(p2_new[0, 1])), (int(p4_new[0, 0]), int(p4_new[0, 1])), (255, 0, 0), 1)
img = cv2.line(img, (int(p1_new[0, 0]), int(p1_new[0, 1])), (int(p3_new[0, 0]), int(p3_new[0, 1])), (255, 0, 0), 1)

return img
```

The result shows as following:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80dq2.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921249/drawing-angled-rectangles-in-opencv
Go through that.

Comment: Thanks, But I don't want to use contour to extract ROI

Comment: Do you have coordinates for all the 4 vertices? Since you have the center point, rotation, width and height, you can easily compute the corner points and then use the cv2.line(...) function

Comment: So basically draw 4 lines?  Thanks I'll do so :)

Comment: Sure, let me know if it works for you!

Comment: It works. I update my code in my question.
Thanks Zeokav :)

Comment: @XiaoZHENG, I think you should answer your own question instead of giving the code in the question, I find it quite confusing.

Comment: And @XiaoZHENG, for Python3 compatibily, you should also add parenthesis around the argument of `print`. Otherwise, thanks for the code.